# Impact of Blogger's country level redirect on traffic and ranking

Tags: blogger

As many of you know blogger displays different URL for the same blog in the different country. Apart from so many domains, do you see any impact on traffic and ranking? I read that it does affect that as link juice, social counts are lost, but there is no official word on this. 
Please share if you have any experience.

Answer (score 3):

Though all country specific blogger domains have canonical link to the .com, you should however use for linking of your blogger site the .com.

On this way you avoid possible negative impacts, which COULD apply, because the canonical isn't a rule, but a recommendation, so some signals, like social links to different country specific domain endings can and sometimes indeed go lost.